# Pandas how to vectorize a calculation that relies on previous rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy

I'm new to pandas and trying to migrate an indicator from pine script to python.  I have a calculation that relies on previous row values that are dynamically computed to get the values of the current row.  I have only been able to do this using a for loop, and haven't figured out a good way to do this with numpy or with dataframe.apply.  The issue is that this calculation is running extremely slow, too slow to be useable for my purposes. 14 seconds on only 21951 rows.

Does anyone know how to do this in a more efficient way in pandas?  Figuring this out will definitely help me when I build out other indicators as most have some sort of reliance of previous row values.

The dataframe looks like:
[image]

```py
"""
//
// @author LazyBear 
// List of all my indicators: 
// https://docs.google.com/document/d/15AGCufJZ8CIUvwFJ9W-IKns88gkWOKBCvByMEvm5MLo/edit?usp=sharing
// 
study(title="Coral Trend Indicator [LazyBear]", shorttitle="CTI_LB", overlay=true)
src=close
sm =input(21, title="Smoothing Period")
cd = input(0.4, title="Constant D")
ebc=input(false, title="Color Bars")
ribm=input(false, title="Ribbon Mode")
"""

# @jit(nopython=True) -- Tried this but was getting an error ==> argument 0: Cannot determine Numba type of <class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
def coral_trend_filter(df, sm = 21, cd = 0.4):
  new_df = df.copy()

  di = (sm - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
  c1 = 2 / (di + 1.0)
  c2 = 1 - c1
  c3 = 3.0 * (cd * cd + cd * cd * cd)
  c4 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd * cd + cd + cd * cd * cd)
  c5 = 3.0 * cd + 1.0 + cd * cd * cd + 3.0 * cd * cd

  new_df['i1'] = 0
  new_df['i2'] = 0
  new_df['i3'] = 0
  new_df['i4'] = 0
  new_df['i5'] = 0
  new_df['i6'] = 0

  for i in range(1, len(new_df)):
    new_df.loc[i, 'i1'] = c1*new_df.loc[i, 'close'] + c2*new_df.loc[i - 1, 'i1']
    new_df.loc[i, 'i2'] = c1*new_df.loc[i, 'i1'] + c2*new_df.loc[i - 1, 'i2']
    new_df.loc[i, 'i3'] = c1*new_df.loc[i, 'i2'] + c2*new_df.loc[i - 1, 'i3']
    new_df.loc[i, 'i4'] = c1*new_df.loc[i, 'i3'] + c2*new_df.loc[i - 1, 'i4']
    new_df.loc[i, 'i5'] = c1*new_df.loc[i, 'i4'] + c2*new_df.loc[i - 1, 'i5']
    new_df.loc[i, 'i6'] = c1*new_df.loc[i, 'i5'] + c2*new_df.loc[i - 1, 'i6']

  new_df['cif'] = -cd*cd*cd*new_df['i6'] + c3*new_df['i5'] + c4*new_df['i4'] + c5*new_df['i3']
  new_df.dropna(inplace=True)
  
  # trend direction
  new_df['cifd'] = 0

  # trend direction color
  new_df['cifd'] = 'blue'
  
  new_df['cifd'] = np.where(new_df['cif'] < new_df['cif'].shift(-1), 1, -1)
  new_df['cifc'] = np.where(new_df['cifd'] == 1, 'green', 'red')


  new_df.drop(columns=['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4', 'i5', 'i6'], inplace=True)

  return new_df

df = coral_trend_filter(data_frame)
```

**Comment response**:
One suggestion was to use shift.  This does not work due to each row calculation being updated at each iteration.  Shifting stores initial values and does not update the shifted columns, thus the computed values are wrong.  See this screenshot that does not match the original in the cif column.  Also note that I left in shifted_i1 to show that the columns remain 0, which is incorrect for the calculation.

[image]

**Update**:
By changing to using `.at` instead of `.loc` I have gotten significantly better performance.  My issue may have been I was using the wrong accessor this type of processing.

Comment: Replace dataframes as pictures with text? Please edit your post so as to share all [code, data and error tracebacks as **text, not images**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557). 
To share dataframes: output of `print(df)` or `print(df.to_dict())`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the following to replace the iteration over rows of the dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# sample dataframe
rng = np.random.default_rng(0)
new_df = pd.DataFrame({'close': rng.integers(1, 10, 10)})
new_df['i1'] = 0
new_df['i2'] = 0

c1 = 3
c2 = 2

N = len(new_df)
exps = c2**np.r_[:N - 1]
f = lambda x: c1 * np.convolve(new_df.loc[1:, x], exps, mode='full')[:N - 1]
new_df.loc[1:, 'i1'] = f('close')
new_df.loc[1:, 'i2'] = f('i1')
```

You can compute the values of the columns `'i3'`, `'i4'` etc. by repeating the last line with the new columns names.

Comment: This approach works!  Only thing is its slower because you have to process the dataframe multiple times due to the multiple np.convolve's, somes comes out slower than the for loop approach.  Also why does a `**` work in the exps part?  The answer is right  I just don't understand why that works :)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like vectorization is only useful when the calculation can be split up and process in parallel per @hpaulj's comment.  I have solved the speed issue by converting to array and doing the loop against the array, then saving the result back into the DataFrame. Here's the code, hope it helps anyone else

```py
"""
//
// @author LazyBear 
// List of all my indicators: 
// https://docs.google.com/document/d/15AGCufJZ8CIUvwFJ9W-IKns88gkWOKBCvByMEvm5MLo/edit?usp=sharing
// 
study(title="Coral Trend Indicator [LazyBear]", shorttitle="CTI_LB", overlay=true)
src=close
sm =input(21, title="Smoothing Period")
cd = input(0.4, title="Constant D")
ebc=input(false, title="Color Bars")
ribm=input(false, title="Ribbon Mode")
"""
def coral_trend_filter(df, sm = 25, cd = 0.4):
  new_df = df.copy()

  di = (sm - 1.0) / 2.0 + 1.0
  c1 = 2 / (di + 1.0)
  c2 = 1 - c1
  c3 = 3.0 * (cd * cd + cd * cd * cd)
  c4 = -3.0 * (2.0 * cd * cd + cd + cd * cd * cd)
  c5 = 3.0 * cd + 1.0 + cd * cd * cd + 3.0 * cd * cd

  new_df['i1'] = 0
  new_df['i2'] = 0
  new_df['i3'] = 0
  new_df['i4'] = 0
  new_df['i5'] = 0
  new_df['i6'] = 0

  close = new_df['close'].to_numpy()
  i1 = new_df['i1'].to_numpy()
  i2 = new_df['i2'].to_numpy()
  i3 = new_df['i3'].to_numpy()
  i4 = new_df['i4'].to_numpy()
  i5 = new_df['i5'].to_numpy()
  i6 = new_df['i6'].to_numpy()

  for i in range(1, len(close)):
    i1[i] = c1*close[i] + c2*i1[i-1]
    i2[i] = c1*i1[i] + c2*i2[i-1]
    i3[i] = c1*i2[i] + c2*i3[i-1]
    i4[i] = c1*i3[i] + c2*i4[i-1]
    i5[i] = c1*i4[i] + c2*i5[i-1]
    i6[i] = c1*i5[i] + c2*i6[i-1]

  new_df['i1'] = i1
  new_df['i2'] = i2
  new_df['i3'] = i3
  new_df['i4'] = i4
  new_df['i5'] = i5
  new_df['i6'] = i6

  new_df['cif'] = -cd*cd*cd*new_df['i6'] + c3*new_df['i5'] + c4*new_df['i4'] + c5*new_df['i3']
  new_df.dropna(inplace=True)
  
  new_df['cifd'] = 0
  new_df['cifd'] = np.where(new_df['cif'] < new_df['cif'].shift(), 1, -1)
  new_df['cifc'] = np.where(new_df['cifd'] == 1, 'green', 'red')

  new_df.drop(columns=['i1', 'i2', 'i3', 'i4', 'i5', 'i6'], inplace=True)

  return new_df
```

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Looks like this method won't work due to the serial nature of the problem. Leaving up for posterity.

It's never good to iterate through a `dataframe` like you're doing with the `for` loop. `Pandas` is ultimately just a wrapper for `Numpy`, so it's best to figure out how to do vectorized array operations. There is basically always a way.

For your case, I would look into using [`pd.DataFrame.shift`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.shift.html) to get your `i - 1` values in the same row and then use [`apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html) (or not - probably not actually) with that new value.

Something like this (for your first couple points):

```py
new_df["shifted_i1"] = new_df["i1"].shift(periods=1)
new_df["i1"] = c1 * new_df["close"] + c2 * new_df["shifted_i1"]

new_df["shifted_i2"] = new_df["i2"].shift(periods=1)
new_df["i2"] = c1 * new_df["i1"] + c2 * new_df["shifted_i2"])

new_df["shifted_i3"] = new_df["i3"].shift(periods=1)
new_df["i3"] = c1 * new_df["i2"] + c2 * new_df["shifted_i3"])

...
```

After this operation you can delete the shifted columns from the dataframe: `new_df.drop(columns=["shifted_i1", "shifted_i2", "shifted_i3"], inplace=True)`

Comment: Yes the issue I believe is that every row relies on the previous row being updated so you can shift values ahead of time.  So specifically I dont think these are equivalent

```python
new_df.loc[i, 'i1'] = c1*new_df.loc[i, 'close'] + c2*new_df.loc[i - 1, 'i1']
=====
new_df["shifted_i1"] = new_df["i1"].shift(periods=1)
new_df["i1"] = c1 * new_df["close"] + c2 * new_df["shifted_i1"]
```

(Sorry for the formatting cant get new lines working in that code snippet)

Comment: These aren't the same because you can't know i1 ahead of time without doing the calculation on the whole dataframe.  So if you shift i1 into that new column initially it'll just have the initial values throughout the datatable instead of updating as the rows are processed.  I could be mistaken if you have a working example that would help to understand the approach you suggested.  Thanks!

Comment: Just do each shift after the previous calculation is completed then, rather than doing all shifts at the top. I'll edit my answer to show this way.

Comment: You also may not actually need the apply at all..

Comment: Oh I understand your issue now. All the values get updated row by row on each loop... but are the results really different from using the approach I showed? It seems like my answer should give the same results as your for loop.

Comment: I added the output of your suggestion to the question as an edit so you can see the output.  Shift only applies the initial default values to the new columns so they remain 0 and throw off the calculation for each row.

Comment: 'Vectorization' in numpy/pandas is essentially a parallel operation, doing the same thing to all rows at once (yes there's a loop in compiled code, but you don't care).  But you have a serial operation; where order matters.  You may get better speed by working on the array version - provided the dataframe indexing is not needed.

Comment: Ah that makes a lot of sense!  Thanks for the tip